# Youtube Flash banner AdWords

Tags: flash, actionscript, google-ads-api, clicktag

I'm supposed to create a flash banner for youtube using adWords.

According to these specifications

http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1308145&topic=1310862&answer=176108&rd=2

I am required to publish the banner for flash player 4.

according to this guide about clickTags

http://www.flashclicktag.com/

there is a problem when a banner with the following code

```
on (release) {
  if (_root.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL(_root.clickTAG, "_blank");
  }
}
```

is published for flash player 7 or below, but played in flash player 10 in internet explorer (according to the guide, the internet explorer will block the ad as a pop-up).

The suggested workarround for this case is to use "_top" instead of "_blank". however, this would open the link in the same tab instead of a new one and i'm quite sure that's against the adWords rules.

So - what's the propper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of flash advertisements in the agency that I'm working for and my piece of advice is to just stick as strictly with the guidelines provided by the publisher as possible. Not doing so is just a massive headache - they'll prod your banner until they find something wrong and you'll end up having to revert anyway.

Also, often the publisher will implement JavaScript that combats issues like this anyway.

Comment: hello! so what's the most common pitfalls? if i have to publish for flash player 4, does that mean that i have to code in Action Script 1??

Comment: flash player 4 doesn't even support actionscript 1.. these guidelines are contradictory. what's the proper publishing version for a flash adwords ad?